# Is the Eel immortal?

Tags: candy-box-2

If you jump in the sea and float for a while, you’ll start getting assaulted by sharks as well as a large eel or sea snake. I threw everything I had at it but it just won’t die. I even tried slowing time, making an obsidian wall, using all attacks, and summoning demons, but it just keeps coming.

I have two questions:

1. Is it a single eel that keeps coming back and loses health each time you hit it or are they multiple eels, and if you don’t kill it while it is on screen, then it is gone and the next one is a different one with full health?
2. Is it outright immortal? I noticed that no health bar is displayed when it gets hit.

[image: Screenshot of eel passing through unharmed]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After trying to kill it numerous times, I came across the wiki for the game which had [the answer to both questions](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=sea_snake) (assuming the wiki is accurate).

1. It is indeed immortal and cannot be killed.
2. The wiki says “it”, not “they”, which implies that there is only one. However, if you swim in the sea long enough, more and more sea snakes come on screen at the same time as seen below, so the wiki may simply be using inconsistent grammar.

<sub>The immortality of the snakes has the side implication that the sea level is endless (which makes it much more efficient to take the boat than to swim—maybe you get lost underwater and go in the wrong direction). It also means that you can get an unlimited number of candies, but you would need to use the *boots of introspection* to go beneath the seabed so that the snake can’t reach you, though even then, it becomes hard to kill the sharks who drop only a couple of hundred candies per shark anyway, so it’s not much of a candy-mine.</sub>

---

[image: Screenshot of four sea snakes on screen at the same time]

Comment: Back when you could still lower the spell cooldown to 0, I rushed in and spewed fireballs at it. No health bar appears, and in fact the snake does not even collide with you - only its spells do. They can indeed not be killed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the snake is immortal, (I think this has already been established) but you might ask, *If the sea snake isn’t a boss, then what is the point of he Sea being unending and increasing in intensity and danger?*

Well the answer is simple: five *really helpful* inventory items. These are explained in more detail on the wiki, but here is a simple overview:

1. Magic Sponge - lets you squeeze
2. Shell Powder - plus lollipop production
3. Red Shark Fin - plus Fireball damage
4. Green Shark Fin - plus lollipop production
5. Purplle Shark Fin - Lets you cast Black Hole

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it's more than one, because when you get far ahead you get more than one on screen at the same time. And I think it's immortal (i couldn't kill it).

Comment: I’ve only ever seen one. They do come on screen at the same time as sharks, so maybe that gave the [illusion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KZaBR.png) of multiple snakes.

Comment: @Synetech: the longer you are at the sea, the more sea snake you see at once

Comment: @gamehelp16, yes, I noticed that last night while trying to get the purple shark fin. I’ll update my answer to reflect that.